# Find list-item on data attribute after ajax

Tags: jquery

Through a

> $(this).attr('data');

we get the A-to-E data values from a list-item. Like:

```
<li id="action" data="1-$b-$c-$d-$e">You Rock 1</li>
<li id="action" data="2-$b-$c-$d-$e">You Rock 2</li>
<li id="action" data="3-$b-$c-$d-$e">You Rock 3</li>
```

Tried this, but doesn't work:

> var trackData = $("[data='" + ........

**The question**, after handling this with ajax (with result success), is to find the specific li-data clicked - and change the bloody background color of the just clicked list item.

Hope someone has the best lesson for me on this!

Comment: can you show me your Ajax request ? i did not understand what you want exactly

Comment: Just a dataString request like: $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "file", data: dataString, success: function(data){  etc...

Comment: another thing the response "data" contains   the <li id="action" data="1-$b-$c-$d-$e">You Rock 1</li>
<li id="action" data="2-$b-$c-$d-$e">You Rock 2</li>
<li id="action" data="3-$b-$c-$d-$e">You Rock 3</li>

or contains only the data attribute value ?

Comment: The question makes no sense. Please post more code

Comment: And provide a proper explanation

Comment: Solved thanks to Orry below. Sorry if I was not clear in my question. Used this to solve it: $("li[data='" + 2 + "-" + $b + "-" + $c + "-" + $d + "-" + $e + "']").css("background-color", "blue");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li[data]").click(function(){
        //data handling and ajax request here
        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
    });
});
```

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/jfdcezpw/1/

EDIT: to make it more browser-friendly you should use `data-name=""` instead of just `data=""`.

Comment: Thank you Orry! Solved thanks to your answer. Did it this way: $("li[data='" + 2 + "-" + $b + "-" + $c + "-" + $d + "-" + $e + "']").css("background-color", "blue");